# Как создать админку для телеграм бота на Python

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Пишу простого бота на пайтоне, который будет рассылать в определенное время сообщения в группы, в которые его пригласили. В админке нужна возможность редактировать сообщения для каждой группы. Собственно, вопрос:
Как лучше создать админку? В виде веб-интерфейса? Или же непосредственно в телеграме по команде /admin запрашивать пароль и выводить команды?
Если второй вариант, то подскажите, как реализовать? Мб есть у кого готовые примеры? Желательно с комментариями. Спасибо.
P.s. использую pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: совет на будущее - лучше всего для таких целей подойдет использовать джанго) даст админ панель с огромными возможностями без лишних заморочек

Answer (score 2):

Думаю второй вариант для вас будет проще.

Для начала сделайте так, чтобы бот админские команды принимал только от вас, а остальные игнорировал, это можно сделать, проверяя user_id того, кто пишет.

Далее сделайте подобные команды:

`\list` - список всех чатов, в которые его прикласили.

`\text [channel]` - текущий текст установленый для канала @channel

`\text_set [channel] [text]` - установка нового текста для канала (ну либо без последнего параметра, а текст кидать в следующем сообщении).

Для хранения "текстов" можно использовать любую базу данных (postgres например), или в крайнем случае, если возможности использовать базу нету, можно сохранять все в словарь, и после этого упаковывать его, например используя [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)